# How to lock specific cpuId with flink taskmanager solt?

Tags: apache-flink

Recently,I am learning flink,I want to konw how could i to lock specific cup whit a solt to avoid cpu change.
I find net.openhft.affinity can lock cpu,but flink has anything configuration can set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do specific slot->CPU (or even slot->Server) assignment in Flink.